# how to make complex selectors with 'this' jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an event handler that needs to do something to one of its children, based on some saved data. So what I'm currently doing is something like this:

```
// Get the ID of 'this'
item_id = $(this).attr('id');

// building a selector like $('#item1 .child_3')
$('#' + item_id + ' .child_' + spVal).addClass('blah');
```

But this seems a little cumbersome. I've tried:

```
$(this + ' .child_' + spVal).addClass('blah');
```

and it doesn't work, which doesn't really surprise me. Is there a better way to do this then the successful way I've outlined above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) (any descendant), or [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) (only direct children), like this:

```
$(this).find('.child_' + spVal).addClass('blah');
```

`.find()` is equivalent to what you currently have, `.children()` would be equivalent to this:

```
$('#' + item_id + ' > .child_' + spVal).addClass('blah');
```

Comment: I've never had the cause to use .find before - thanks for the new toy :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can select the children like this as well:

```
$(this).children('.child_' + spVal).addClass('blah');
```